# How To fix "ServerScriptService.Earthquake:11: attempt to index nil with 'OnServerEvent'"

Tags: lua, roblox

Ive been through the code multiple times and cant find anything that would cause this. Am I just being blind and if so can you point me in the right direction please.

Heres my code:

```
local rp = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local remote = rp:WaitForChild("Earthquake")

local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local Debris = game:GetService("Debris")

local Meshes = script:WaitForChild("Meshes")

local damage = 15

remote.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    local char = player.Character
    local humrp = char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
    local hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

    local folder = Instance.new("Folder", workspace)
    folder.Name = player.Name.."'s Earthquake"

    local anim = hum:LoadAnimation(script:WaitForChild("anim"))
    anim:Play()

    wait(0.9)

    for count = 1, 15 do 
        local rock = Meshes:WaitForChild("rock"):Clone()
        rock.Parent = folder
        rock.Size = Vector3.new(math.random(4,9),0.05,math.random(4,9))
        rock.Cframe = humrp.CFrame * CFrame.new(0,3,-count*6)
        rock.Orientation = rock.Orientation + Vector3.new(math.random(-20,20),math.random(-20,20),math.random(-20,20))



        local tweenRand = math.random(7,15)




        local tween =  TweenService:Create(rock, TweenInfo.new(0.2),{Size = rock.Size + Vector3.new(0, tweenRand,0), Position = rock.Position + Vector3.new(0,(tweenRand/2)-3,0)})
        tween:Play()

        wait(0.1)
    end
end)
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the Earthquake RemoteEvent is in UserInputService? Are you sure it not in ReplicatedStorage or the Workspace or somewhere else?

Comment: @Kylaaa Your right it was in replicated storage but how do i put it in UIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that on line 11, `remote` is nil, this means that line 2 is failing to find the RemoteEvent in UserInputService. Based on the comments on the question, the RemoteEvent isn't in UserInputService, it's actually in ReplicatedStorage.

To fix this, just update your code so it points at the ReplicatedStorage.

```
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remote = rs:WaitForChild("Earthquake")
```